# Package swig-wx not found in rxtools in Groovy

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, rxtools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a package that depends on rxtools which in turn depends on swig-wx. My package will not compile in Groovy since it says that swig-wx does not exist. Running  rosdep check on my package results in "resource not found [swig-wx]", but ros-groovy-swig-wx is installed:

```
 $ rosdep resolve swig-wx
 #apt
 ros-groovy-swig-wx
```

Does this have to do with rxtools being deprecated in Groovy? Everything works fine in Fuerte.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52023/package-swig-wx-not-found-in-rxtools-in-groovy/) by [Ola Ringdahl](https://answers.ros.org/users/1011/ola-ringdahl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2013-01-11

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-05-10**:
The deprecation tag in the package.xml is only informational and has no functional effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have a similar problem.

Here is the error log for compiling cob_bringup:

```
fxm@sony-fxm:~/projects/groovy/care-o-bot/cob_robots/cob_bringup$ make
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package cob_bringup
[rosbuild] Cached build flags older than manifests; calling rospack to get flags
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/groovy/bin/rospack cflags-only-I;--deps-only cob_bringup
Package swig-wx was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `swig-wx.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'swig-wx' found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/rospack.py", line 45, in call_pkg_config
    value = subprocess.check_output(['pkg-config', option, pkg_name])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 544, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['pkg-config', '--cflags-only-I', 'swig-wx']' returned non-zero exit status 1
[rospack] Error: could not call python function 'rosdep2.rospack.call_pkg_config'


CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
  

  Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'cob_bringup'.
  Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the
  broken dependency!

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:227 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (rosbuild_init)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

We were able to build and run our simulation after commenting the swig-wx related lines in /opt/ros/groovy/share/rxtools/package.xml.
However, manipulating read-only files can't be the final solution...

Any suggestions? Thank you!

---

Originally posted by [Felix Messmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/208/felix-messmer/) with karma: 198 on 2013-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2